# What is a good word or prhase to describe a unit of measure/a unit of physical quantity?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, programming

I am looking for a good word or a short phrase to describe a physical quantity.

For example consider these examples:

- 5.0 m<sup>3</sup>/h
- 17 bar
- 20 gpm (gallons per minute)
- 3 psi (pounds per square inch)

I am looking for a word or phrase that accurately describes the text on the right side of the number in above examples (bar, gpm, meters, etc).

In the past I've used words like unit, but I do not feel that they represent the concept properly or distinctly.

My context of use is in programming code and naming variables, so when I just say 'unit', it is seen as ambiguous - am I referring to Metric/English unit system, or unit of measurement?

Comment: Have you tried Wikipedia? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_of_measurement

Comment: *A unit of measurement is a definite **magnitude** of a quantity.*

Comment: What's wrong with the term you're using, "unit of measurement"?

Comment: Business types use "metric" as a generic way to refer to various quantities such as Earnings/sh. or EBITDA (Earnings Before Income Taxes, Depreciation, and Amortization). But it's not really clear what you are asking, as you have not given an example of where the word or phrase would go.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's off-topic as defined in the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help). Names of programming variables are off-topic.

Comment: The *International System of Units* is the absolute gold standard for terminology. Even if your program deals with tiddlywinks per acre-foot-day, follow the conventions of SI and you’ll come round right.

Comment: "unit of measurement" is probably the most descriptive term, it's just too long. unit/denomination are too ambiguous, ...

Comment: @Rusty, yes I have been looking at WikiPedia, but so far nothing caught my eye definitively..

Comment: The only other single word I can think of that's related is **portion** (or possibly simply **measure**). But if you don't like **unit**, you probably won't like it either. It also depends on the specific context. Are you talking about something to describe the specific variable word (or symbol) or the thing that's being measured, regardless of how it's described?

Comment: I am talking about the variable but in a greater context I am trying to name variables to convey the concept of what is being described.  I resolved to call it `unit_of_measure`.  It's longer than I would have liked, but it is relatively unambiguous

Comment: The "metric system" isn't "'the metric unit" for good reason: "Unit" refers to what one of a number means. "Systems" of units are the conventional sets thereof. There isn't ambiguity in using "unit" and even if there was, that's what comments are for. "unit //stores the unit of measurement" would get everyone on the same page without a long variable name.

Comment: In the codebase I inherited there are database tables with a column called `unit`, which stores `M` or `E`, for Metric or English respectively.  That later gets assigned to a variable called `$unit`, which is then used for unit system needs, such as unit conversions.  Some programmer before me had done this.  Ideally perhaps `unit` should mean unit of measure, and `system` should be unit system.  Nowadays I try to make variables short yet descriptive.  I figure that `unit_of_measure`, and `unit_system` are not so bad and it will be quite hard to misinterpret them later.

Comment: They are called unit(s). Meters per seconds i.e. m/s is called velocity. So, here m/s and v both are units. Some ratio of units don't have name and some do have. Here, we name m/s as velocity. So, they are just called **units.**